# Selecting multiple columns and set it to list of DTOs

Tags: mysql, sql, database, jpa, jpql

I want to get multiple columns from database in a single query and set it to the corresponding DTO object fields.

Error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node:
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.IdentNode
 +-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'payment' {originalText=payment}
```

Query:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT
payment, createdOn,responseMessage FROM PaymentLog log WHERE log.id
=:personId", Object[].class);

query.setParameter("personId",new BigInteger(basicEntityDto.getId()));
List<Object[]> results =  query.getResultList();

for (Object[] log : results) {
   paymentTransaction.setAmount(log[0].toString());
   paymentTransaction.setDate(log[1].toString());
   paymentTransaction.setDescription(log[2].toString());
   transactionList.add(paymentTransaction);
}
```

P.S. I know I can use JPA constructor expression. But as I have to add the DTOs in a list of DTO(i.e. transactionList), so is there a way with JPA construction expression where I can do that by running the query only one time instead in a loop for every single DTO?

Comment: how can anyone say if there is anything "wrong" with the query when you don't post the entities that are used here? I have no crystal ball, but maybe others do

Answer (score 0):

You can have the JPA provider transform the result set for you by means of a constructor expression:

http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#Constructors

This requires that the specified class has a constructor matching the select expression. This would then look something like the below:

```
TypedQuery<PaymentTransaction> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new PaymentTransaction (log.payment, log.createdOn, log.responseMessage ) FROM PaymentLog log WHERE log.id
=:personId", PaymentTransaction.class);
query.setParameter("personId",new BigInteger(basicEntityDto.getId()));
List<PaymentTransaction> results =  query.getResultList();
```

In JPA 2.1 you can also so like the below:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying#ConstructorResult_.28JPA_2.1.29

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is:

```
TypedQuery<PaymentLog> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT log FROM PaymentLog log WHERE log.id =:personId", PaymentLog.class);

query.setParameter("personId",new BigInteger(basicEntityDto.getId()));
List<PaymentLog> results =  query.getResultList();

for (PaymentLog log : results) {
   paymentTransaction.setAmount(log.getPayment());
   paymentTransaction.setDate(log.getCreatedOn());
   paymentTransaction.setDescription(log.getResponseMessage());
   transactionList.add(paymentTransaction);
}
```

It is not a good idea to select everything from the database if you are not going to use it. If the selected fields were the only columns in the table then approach above works.

If you had a lot more columns in the table, the previous would still work, but this might be better:

```
TypedQuery<PaymentTransaction> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT new PaymentTransaction (log.payment, log.createdOn, log.responseMessage) FROM PaymentLog log WHERE log.id =:personId", PaymentTransaction.class);
query.setParameter("personId",new BigInteger(basicEntityDto.getId()));
List<PaymentTransaction> results =  query.getResultList();
```

The above query will return an already created list of PaymentTransactions. You have to note that the class `PaymentTransaction`should have a constructor that accept these fields in the given order. Otherwise it will cause an exception